# ERROR SQL Server ONLY one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run my query but I get an error.

This is my query:

```
if exists (select CODE_ISIN 
           from cte 
           where code_ISIN not in (select [STATUT_TITRE], [CODE_ISIN] 
                                   from TT_TITRE A 
                                   inner join TT_STATUT_TITRE B on A.TITRE_ID = B.TITRE_ID))
begin
    select 'ko'
end
begin
    select 'ok'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `[STATUT_TITRE]` from sub-query as it will accept only one expression :

```
select c.CODE_ISIN 
from cte c 
where code_ISIN not in (select [CODE_ISIN] -- only one expression needed
                        from TT_TITRE A inner join 
                             TT_STATUT_TITRE B 
                             on A.TITRE_ID = B.TITRE_ID
                        );
```

I would suggest to use `NOT EXISTS` instead :

```
where not exists (select 1 
                  from TT_TITRE A inner join 
                       TT_STATUT_TITRE B 
                       on A.TITRE_ID=B.TITRE_ID
                  where CODE_ISIN = c.CODE_ISIN 
                );
```

Comment: but i want to add condition

Comment: @badiszakaria: You can add conditions to WHERE without listing the column in the SELECT-list

Comment: It's not so much "only one expression needed" as only one expression _allowed_. If the OP wants to check against another column they can either `union all` a second query with the additional values (`... not in ( select Col1 ... union all select Col2 ... )`) or use two `exists` expressions (`... not ( exists ( select 42 ... ) or exists ( select 42 ...) )`).